# Minor (16 years old) travelling by himself from Cape Town to Paris via Doha: any special formalities required? Thanks

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, france, south-africa, doha

Our 16 year old son is travelling from Cape Town via Doha. What documents/authorizations does he need? Thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Should the answer include passport and visa requirements, or are you only interested in letters of permission and the like?  If the former, we would need to know your son's nationality.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now